# Assembly @@ label question

Tags: assembly

I have been looking at some assembly code and have found that this comes up rather regularly.

```
@@: 
...
... ; some instructions
...
LOOP @B
```

Sometimes there is also @F.

I suppose that @B means to go back to the previous label and @F the the "forward/front" label? Am I right? This only works with "@@" labels? If I have label "label1" and used @B, would that work too?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've got it figured out.

These are most useful in macro expansions.  If your macro contains a loop, using these built-in symbols allow you to write the macro such that it can be expanded more than once.  If your macro were required to use a standard label, expanding the macro twice would create duplicated labels.

These relative label references (`@B`, `@F`) never refer to normally-defined labels, only to `@@`.

Here are some documentation links:

- [@@](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0470281w(VS.71).aspx)
- [@B](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ac5tket9(VS.71).aspx)
- [@F](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kdtf86c4(VS.71).aspx)
- [Microsoft Macro Assembler Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/afzk3475(VS.71).aspx)